# How do I dynamically populate a select field?

Tags: 7, ajax, taxonomy-terms

this question comes quite often but I couldn't make it work to that point.
My problem is simple, I have a 2 level taxonomy, I have 2 select fields, one is populated with the parent taxonomy and the second should be populated by its children when one parent is selected.

But I'm a bit confused. I followed the developer example with the check-boxes, but still. Also, this happens in `hook_form_alter()` and since I'm quite new to Drupal 7, I have to set the options with the `['und']` prefix, but that also troubles my mind because when I omit the `['und']` part when I try to save the node, an error says *Illegal choice*.

This is my first select field.

```
  //Field TYPE
  $form['field_type']['und']['#options'] = std_to_array($vocabulary_nudge_all);
  $form['field_type']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_nudge_taxonomy_selected_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'select-target-div',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  );
```

This is the AJAX callback function where I tried to get the *field_type* value, but I read somewhere that I couldn't use `$form_state` in a form hook.

```
function ajax_nudge_taxonomy_selected_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_target_select'];
}
```

Using `$form`, all I could think of was using `#delta`.

```
$selected = $form['field_type']['und']['#delta']
```

In the second select with a prefix, a suffix, and a visible condition, I am using the following code.

```
//Field Target SELECT
$form['field_target_select']['#weight'] = '0';
$form['field_target_select']['#prefix'] = '<div id="select-target-div">';
$form['field_target_select']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['field_target_select']['und']['#options'] = std_to_array($vocabulary_nudge_all);
$form['field_target_select']['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_type[und]"]' => array(
      array('value' => 'carroussel'),
      array('value' => 'vitrine'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I know there would be a solution by creating several select fields with visible conditions, but later more taxonomy fields could be added.

Right now it's not even doing the AJAX call anymore, and I can't manage to fix this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I read somewhere that I couldn't use $form_state in a form hook

Not quite. If `hook_form_alter()` is being executed for the first time, then yes, `$form_state` can't be used to get a field's value because `$form_state['values']` will not be set.

However, if `hook_form_alter()` is being **re-executed**, like from an `#ajax` callback, then `$form_state['values']` will be set with the current form values, just like it would be in `#submit[]` and `#validate[]` functions. By the way, the `$form['#validate'][]` functions are also executed during an `#ajax` callback.

In your case, I believe you would get the current value of `field_type` from `$form_state['values']['field_type'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]` (best to use the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE` instead of the string `'und'`). Wherever you build the `#options` array for `field_target_select` during the execution of `hook_form_alter()`, you would do something like this:

```
$selected = 'some_default_value';
if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_type'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
  $selected = $form_state['values']['field_type'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
}
$child_options = my_function_to_get_child_options($selected);
$form['field_target_select'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'] = $child_options;
```

What you have as your ajax callback function in your question looks correct:

```
function ajax_nudge_taxonomy_selected_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_target_select'];
}
```